# Azure AD show group name in id token instead of group id

Tags: azure-active-directory, jwt

My id token has group (as role) ids only

```
"roles": [
    "729b24b5-c527-440e-9ef6-81a04415e7ba",
    "8d4f9343-10c3-43a2-9efe-34cfd740d020",
    "81715416-9be4-43d7-807a-d5ccc9420cf7",
    "1b5e6d7b-0ee0-4212-a5b9-cd5c3ca07a4a"
  ],
```

Even set to `sAMAccountName`

[image]

Any idea to return the group names instead?

Comment: please refer to this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59873599/include-aad-group-name-in-the-jwt-token) and let us know if it helps

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are expecting group names in the claims of ID/Access/SAML token, unfortunately currently that is not supported due to some limitations. You would only have the object ids (guid) of the groups in the claim for AAD managed groups.

If you absolutely need group names for your purpose, consider a separate [Graph API call](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-list-memberof?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) to list group memberships of a user.

Also feel free to upvote on the feature request of group names in [claims here](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169401-azure-active-directory/suggestions/38483242-option-to-show-group-name-in-groups-claims).

Please refer to this [similar question](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/59766#issuecomment-664387195)

Comment: Ended up using Application roles instead.

Answer (score 3):

This is relatively old, but there's answer to that.

You can translate your groups to names by adjusting your application manifest.

Go to your application manifest via Applications and SSO options, you should see there "Manifest option" it should return a JSON which you can modify.

The important bit is in the optionalClaims, you need to add to your `groups.additionalProperties` section `cloud_displayname` option like this:

```
...
    "optionalClaims": {
        "idToken": [
            {
                "name": "preferred_username",
                "source": null,
                "essential": false,
                "additionalProperties": []
            },
            {
                "name": "groups",
                "source": null,
                "essential": false,
                "additionalProperties": [
                    "sam_account_name",
                    "emit_as_roles",
                    "cloud_displayname"
                ]
            }
        ],
...
```

Comment: could you share how the groups are looking then in the oidc token? because i'm not able to acces it, in groups i still get the ids and groups.additionalProperties is empty

Answer (score 1):

This is now supported if you select **Groups assigned to the application**. So you must assign to the enterprise app the groups of users allowed to sign-in.

Select **sAMAccountName** as source attribute and tick **Emit group name for cloud-only groups**.

[image: enable group names in SAML claims]

Comment: hmm, only works for groups synchronized from an on-premises AD.

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is rather old already, but I experienced the same issue in summer 2021 still when trying to create a new .NET API project. Probably people stumbling across it in 2021 could make use of my solution:

I decided to create a NuGet package that resolves the group names using Microsoft Graph for applications using .NETs `Microsoft.Identity.Web` package (mostly ASP.NET Core applications).

Feel free to take a look into https://github.com/peterwurzinger/AuthOida if that's applicable to your use case.